# Import Spring Roo data model in Drools

Tags: spring-roo, drools, drools-guvnor

I have generated a web app (Spring MVC-style) based on a MYSQL db using Spring Roo. I'd like to know what's the easiest way to export the data model to Drools Workbench? I know it's possible to import jars in the Drools repository, but how can I generate this jar from Spring Roo and make sure it has all the classes needed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does Roo use compile-time or run-time annotations? If run-time, you'll need the libs is classpath. Otherwise it should be just a jar file uploaded

Comment: Roo uses loads of compile time annotations along with heavy use of AspectJ to inject features such as transaction management. There's a whole load of stuff that would need to be placed on the Guvnor/Workbench server classpath. A couple of years back I made the decision to separate my persistence models and map to simple Drools facts which had no external dependencies (well except for Joda time). My development life has been much easier ever since.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Maven Assembly plugin to generate the Jar you need